# Esconder a URL de destino

Tags: javascript, jquery

No exemplo do jquery os argumentos são bem identificados; url e os parametros de formulário.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
}).done(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Quero saber se tem alguma forma de ocultar a url no ajax ou dificultar ao maximo a identificação do destino para evitar que seja copiado e colado no navegador.

Vejo o js de outros sites e aparentemente são javascript puro.
Isso implica em segurança em alguma forma?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui depois http://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Que linguagem você usa no servidor? É possível identificar se a requisição veio mesmo por ajax, e responder com um erro se não tiver vindo.

Comment: Você pode colocar em um arquivo .JS separado e minificado, já dificulta um pouco, criptografar a  URL e usar uma função para descriptografar na hora de usar, já impede a visualização direta, mas se o usuário estiver determinado a ver a URL, nada pode ser feito.

Comment: Ou melhor ainda usar um ofuscador como [este](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)

Comment: Qual sua linguagem no lado servidor?

Comment: Uso PHP, mas a variavel $_SERVER, é 100% garantido? Dizem que as requisições podem ser 'simuladas'

Comment: @Orion, obrigado pelo link, estou lendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, na verdade não existe maneira de esconder nem a url nem os valores.

Agora tem algumas medidas que caso haja necessidade podem ser tomadas, como:

- **Adicionar uma regra restrita de CORS no seu servidor**

Com isso você pode restringir a utilização da sua api ou seja o que for, a dominios especificos.

Ex: Você tem uma url que cadastra o usuário, você pode no servidor configurar para que apenas o site www.meusite.com com possa acessar, com isso um outro site qualquer vai receber um erro ao tentar acessar. ( Isso é browser que barra, um CURL já funciona)

- **Criptografar**

Alguns dados mais sigilosos podem ser criptografados de modo que não sirvam de nada para quem interceptar.
Ex: Quero enviar meu usuário e minha senha e quero proteger esses dados, posso fazer um MD5 e enviar, também existem outras alternativos como bcrypt.. etc.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar em `CORS`, vou procurar, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Esquece isso! Se você encriptar alguém pode desencriptar, se você ofuscar alguém pode desofuscar (existe essa palavra?).

Se o problema é o usuário acessar uma página direto pelo endereço você deve verificar na requisição desta página se o método de chamada dele é o esperado. Por exemplo, GET ou POST.

Comment: obrigado... eu so PHP, a variavel $_SERVER dizem que as requisições podem ser 'simuladas' é seguro?

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] pode usar sem medo!

Answer (score 1):

Como desencriptografar um MD5 256 ou um bcrypt baseado em hash de comparação?

A possibilidade é claro que existe, mas o custo para fazer isso é muito grande e muito lento, no caso do bcrypt posso te afirmar que é quase impossível, já que o hash gerado é sempre diferente e tem que ser comparado através de um algoritmo lento.

Quanto a desofuscar não entendi tecnicamente como seria feito, como desofuscaria um CORS no browser?

Quanto aos metodos POST e GET não mudam em nada a segurança dos dados, a unica diferença é que o GET envia na query e o POST no payload do HTTP.

Concluindo, não.. não esqueça isso. Leve em consideração proteger seu servidor com CORS e pelo bem dos seus usuários utilize um algoritmo de criptografia para os dados sensiveis.

Comment: O custo não compensa! Encriptar a url somente para evitar que o usuário não tenha acesso a ela pelo código, quando na verdade ele pode capturar depois da requisição ser realizada!

Comment: Em nenhum momento eu falei de encriptar a url, e sim os dados. Quanto a url no servidor pode ser adicionada uma regra de CORS que não tem nada com criptografia e sim com restrição de uso pelo browser.

Comment: Sim no caso de ofuscar seria o endereço da url. Quanto ao CORS é uma boa também. Ao que parece ele já está utilizando o request_method!